# Parameter sent to SQL Server stored procedure not recognized

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am in Visual Studio 2010 using C# and connection to a SQL Server 2008 database. I am calling a stored procedure and passing it a parameter. I am getting the error message below.

I have checked the parameter being passed and the name and value are correct and the connection is open, the stored procedure name is also correct. If I set a default value for the parameter it does return the corresponding rows. Below the error message I have put the code that is being executed. The values being passed to `Parameters.AddWithValue` are `ParmName = @DetailCategoryID`, `ParmValue = 2`. When I execute the exact same code using Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition it works perfectly.

> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [42000]
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Procedure or function
>   'spGET_Detail' expects parameter '@DetailCategoryID', which was not
>   supplied.\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle,
>   RetCode retcode)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments,
>   SQL_API odbcApiMethod)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader()\r\n
>   at DataAccess.OpenReader() in
>   C:\Development\DetailRetrieval\DetailRetrieval\Classes\DataAccess.cs:line
>   1252

The code

```
this.DB_Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue(ParmName, ParmValue);
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spGET_Detail
    @DetailCategoryID smallint
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT F.* FROM dbo.tbDetail_MSTR AS F
    WHERE (F.DetailCategoryID = @DetailCategoryID)
    ORDER BY [F].[Description]
END
GO
```

I would greatly appreciate any help anybody can offer.

Thank You

Comment: So `ParmName = @DetailID`, and `parameter '@DetailCategoryID'` is expected, but you're saying the name is okay?

Comment: Can you include your calling code not just the sp definition? That would be helpful.

Comment: Hi BenR, here is the calling code -> DA.StoredProcedure = _StoredProc; DA.ParametersClear(); // Load parameters foreach (string o in _Parms) { DA.ParametersAdd(o, _ParmVals[p]); p++; } if (DA.OpenReader()) public bool ParametersAdd(string IN_ParmName, object IN_ParmValue) { bool Ret = true; try { this.DB_Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue(IN_ParmName, IN_ParmValue); } catch(Exception ex) { this.Except = ex.ToString(); Ret = false; } return Ret }

Answer (score 3):

The error gives you all the information you need:

> Procedure or function 'spGET_Detail' expects parameter '**@DetailCategoryID**',

But you said

> ParmName = **@DetailID**

**Edit**: I just realized that you are using the ODBC driver to connect to SQL server. The ODBC driver uses question marks as parameter place holders, not named parameters. So your query should not have @anything.  The parameters are replaced based on order, not name.

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbw6zyha.aspx

The syntax for parameter placeholders depends on the data source. This example shows placeholders for a SQL Server data source. Use question mark (?) placeholders for System.Data.OleDb and System.Data.Odbc parameters.

That said, unless you are going to be connecting to a lot of other database types, you probably should use SqlClient, not ODBC.

Comment: That was a mistype on my part. The parameter name and what I pass it are correct.  It should be @DetailCategoryID.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
his.DB_Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("DetailCategoryID", 2);
```

Comment: This.  Basically it sounds like the OP is passing the @ sign as part of the parameter name.  You don't need to do that.

Comment: Hi Chris, I tried passing the parameter without the "@" and got the same result.

Comment: Hi BenR, here is the calling code ->             DA.StoredProcedure = _StoredProc;
            DA.ParametersClear();
            // Load parameters
            foreach (string o in _Parms)
            {
                DA.ParametersAdd(o, _ParmVals[p]);
                p++;
            }

            if (DA.OpenReader())
 public bool ParametersAdd(string IN_ParmName, object IN_ParmValue)
 {
  bool Ret = true;

  try
  {
            this.DB_Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue(IN_ParmName, IN_ParmValue);
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
   this.Except = ex.ToString();
   Ret   = false;
  }
  
return Ret }

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue - Exception said the parameter wasn't there when it was, regardless of having the '@' or not in the parameter name.

I resolved it by setting the command type of the `SqlCommand` object to `StoredProcedure`:

```
DB_Comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

PS - It doesn't matter if you have the @ in the parameter name with this method.  I tested with some @parameters and others without in the same sproc call and it worked.